# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package with no obvious cause

Tags: python, import, directory, package

I'm working with a directory structure shown below, my objective is to use the functions in `functions.py` on the scripts `main_code1.py` and `main_code2.py`. I do this by using the command: `from ...package import functions`. However, I get back the following exception:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Why is this? Does anyone know how to solve it? (I have already tried including **init**.py in every folder).

```
project/
  package/
    __init__.py
    functions.py
  main_code/
    main_code1/
      main_code1.py
  main_code2/
    main_code2.py
```

Comment: Have you had `__init__.py` under `project/`?

Comment: Yes, I did with no success, still the same error.

Comment: Were you trying to run `main_codeX.py` as a script in the command line?

Comment: It runs in python spyder as a script

Comment: Relative imports are not available for scripts. If you have to run it as script, try `python -m`

Comment: See this: https://www.georgevreilly.com/blog/2016/01/17/RelativeImportsInAPythonScript.html

Comment: The weird thing is that I can call the functions by pressing tab, so it seems to know where the functions are, but still get the error, even when trying in the command line.